# Cuál es la explicación de "saldo = saldo * (1+tasa/12) - pago_mensual" en este código?

Tags: python, matemáticas

Éste es un ejercicio resuelto, quisiera que alguien pudiera explicarmelo porque no lo entiendo..
Lo que no entiendo es la linea de código  "saldo = saldo * (1+tasa/12) - pago_mensual"
Ésto me da:
saldo= 499399.19  en la primera iteración. ]
saldo= 498798.39 en la segunda. y así hasta que saldo deje de ser mayor a cero.
¿Pero cuál es la lógica ahí?  no entiendo por qué le resta 600.81 al nuevo "saldo" en cada iteración. por qué el "1 + tasa/12" ?  alguien puede explicarme?

David solicitó un crédito a 30 años para comprar una vivienda, con una tasa fija nominal anual del 5%. Pidió $500000 al banco y acordó un pago mensual fijo de $2684,11.

El siguiente es un programa que calcula el monto total que pagará David a lo largo de los años:

```
saldo = 500000.0
tasa = 0.05
pago_mensual = 2684.11
total_pagado = 0.0

while saldo > 0:
    saldo = saldo * (1+tasa/12) - pago_mensual
    total_pagado = total_pagado + pago_mensual

print('Total pagado', round(total_pagado, 2))
```

Rta: 966279.6

ACLARO: Sí entiendo que divide el 5% por los 12 meses,
Mi duda es por qué le estoy restando $600.81 al saldo en cada iteración. (si es que hice bien la cuenta y es ese el monto). Por qué saldo me queda igual al saldo más la tasa de ese mes menos el pago fijo mensual.

Comment: Lo que preguntas no es de programación es de matemática financiera.

Comment: Revisa [*Interés Compuesto*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter%C3%A9s_compuesto).

Answer (score 1):

No es un problema de programación, sino de aritmética financiera.

La tasa anual del 5% equivale a una tasa mensual de `0,05 / 12` (5% dividido por 12 meses).

Entonces, si te prestan $1000, el primer mes los intereses son

```
interés del mes = $1000 * tasa / 12
```

y luego debes el capital ($1000) y el interés:

```
deuda total = $1000 + $1000 * tasa / 12
```

lo que se simplifica algebraicamente a:

```
deuda total = $1000 * (1 + tasa / 12)
```

Con los intereses aumenta el capital, y con el pago lo rebajas. Después de pagar el primer mes, tu deuda queda en

```
deuda total = $1000 * (1 + tasa / 12) - pago_mensual
```

Comment: Perdon acá me perdí en algo. ese " $1000 * (1 + tasa / 12) - pago_mensual "   en realidad empieza con $500 000, no con $1000. Y todo eso es igual a la variable "sueldo", no igual a la deuda total. (a mi me prestaron $500 000 pero la deuda total es mucho mayor). y la variable "sueldo" va a ir variando en cada iteracion. Esa es la parte que no entiendo.  Por qué, luego de la primera iteración, (que supongo seria "luego del primer mes") le resté 600,81 a 500 000 (a sueldo) y por qué le sigo restando ese monto en cada iteración.

Comment: @danistor_m ya te dijeron que este no es un problema de programación, sino de aritmética financiera, para esto puedes visitar el [sitio de matemáticas](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) donde tu pregunta será mejor recibida

Comment: @danistor_m. Es así como se cualcula. Los valores no importan, ni tampoco que nombre le pongas a las cosas. Es la misma aritmética para cualquier crédito.

Answer (score 0):

El crédito tiene una tasa anual del 5%, o sea, la tasa mensual es 5%/12 (tasa/12). Esto significa que cada mes se le suma esta tasa al saldo (el saldo que debe se va incrementando con los intereses).
El saldo de cada mes es saldo + saldo*tasa/12
Al mismo tiempo cada mes se le resta al saldo (a lo que debe más los intereses) la cuota que paga. Al final del mes el saldo será lo que se debe más los intereses menos lo que se paga como cuota fija.